# Manter a altura de um bloco div proporcional à sua largura

Tags: html5, css3

Olá, tenho um bloco `div` em forma de coluna vertical de largura e altura indeterminados, pois dependem da quantidade de conteudo e do dispositivo, e quero que dentro dele tenha outro bloco `div` no topo que tenha `width: 100%;` mas a altura ( height ) deve ser de 53% em relação a largura ( width ) desse bloco.

Com uma imagem em vez de um bloco div eu consigo fazer usando `max-width: 100%;`, mas claro que eu necessito de um bloco `div`.

Entenda melhor : http://jsfiddle.net/Lbk11L71/1/ .

Não posso usar javascript!

Comment: E o que vai dentro desse *div*? Dê mais informações porque se não precisar ter nada dentro (isto é, somente visual) pode usar `padding`: [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/re22/jfpsgp5L/1/)

Comment: dentro dela quero três blocos proporcionais, um grande flutuando à esquerda e outros dois pequenos flutuando à direita

Comment: O tamanho em porcento dos objetos é relativo ao contexto onde se encontram, nesse caso creio que você vai precisar colocar uma outra div com altura 100% e essa dentro dela com altura relativa.

Comment: Não compreendi bem, tem como você fazer um exemplo no http://jsfiddle.net/ por favor ?!

Comment: já tentou usar um max-width ou max-height.

Comment: sim :-( eu ja tentei

Comment: Ver se minha resposta resolveu seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução parece ser mesmo usar `padding-top`, como sugerido no comentário do @renan e na resposta do @JeffersonAlison. O [padding em CSS é proporcional à largura do container](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties).

```
#a {
    width: 35%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #c64800;
    float: left;
}
#b {
    padding-top: 53%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/92aau9wg/</sup>

Como a largura de `#b` é a mesma de `#a`, a altura de `#b` será 53% de sua largura. E para poder colocar qualquer conteúdo dentro de `#b`, você pode usar um div intermediário:

```
#a {
    width: 35%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #c64800;
    float: left;
}
#intermediario {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 53%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
#b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/nr7wjrg9/</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi direito, mas é algo assim?

```css
#a {
    width: 35%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #c64800;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 40px 40px 0;
}
#b {
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 53%;
    display: block;
    background: url("https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm3jEIkfGsmihCgf2iAOXD6HktQH4XMaq7m4Ia6kedLieWgqG4Cw") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
Observe que consego fazer com uma imagem mas quero esse resultado com uma div.<br/><br/>
O bloco "b" deve sempre manter altura proporcional a sua largura.<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/> <- altere a largura da pagina
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  background:red;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  height: 150px;    

}
#test{
  width: 20%;
}
#test:before{
  content:'';
  padding:50% 0;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
span {
  display:inline-block;
}
.test{
  width: 20%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:yellow;
}
.test:before{
  content:'';
  padding-top:100%;/* valor vertical como 100% igual a largura */ 
  float:left;;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <span> Oi, eu sou o Goku</span>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <span> Oi, eu sou o Goku</span>
</div>
```